# how createScaledBitmap works? Which re-sizing algorithm is used to create the scale image?

Tags: android, bitmap, resize-image

I've used createScaledBitmap in my code but now I want to know which method is used to scale the images. as probably you know there are some interpolation methods to resize images like: 'nearest', 'bilinear' or 'bicubic'. Please if you have reference for your answer let me know.

Comment: nobody knows but skia developers, why is it so important?

Comment: Because I used this method for application and now I'm writing the paper related to it. So I have to mention which method is used to resize. In other words to prove this fact that average of all intensity of pixels in image after resize and before resize is same, I have to know which method is used to resize. !!

Comment: start with that: http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java or http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#1581

Answer (score 0):

`AOSP` project is open-source, it means you can always take a look on source files. You are interested in [createScaledBitmap](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#577) method. If you trace it, you'll see, that it is calling [createBitmap](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#660) method with passing `scaleMatrix`. Going deeper, you'll find that resizing is done via concatenation of `scaleMatrix` and current `Canvas` matrix, which is using native call to do that. This should give your an idea how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I traced them and found that it called native to scale the matrix. But now how can I know how native does this scaling ?

Comment: @FarshadVesali sorry, maybe I'm a bit too late, missed your question, but native implementations you can find here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/